# Unir dos diccionarios procedentes de archivos de texto en los que cada fila es la representación de un diccionario

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios

Tengo dos archivos de texto cada uno con unas 10 lineas de contenido en formato de diccionario cada una:

> {'ID': '30', 'Nombre': 'ECONOMIA I', 'Codigo': 'COFI-214'}
>   {'ID': '30', 'Nombre': 'ECONOMIA II', 'Codigo': 'COFI-215'}
>   ...

Quiero crear un nuevo archivo que me una por ejemplo la linea 1 del primer archivo con la linea 6 del segundo en un mismo diccionario.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

```
infile1 = open('archivo1.txt', 'r')
infile2 = open('archivo2.txt', 'r')
outfile = open("archivounion.txt","w")
```

Comment: Lees cada archivo abierto como `'r'` y escribes lo leído en el archivo abierto como `'w'`...

Comment: crea un arreglo de con una estructura como la siguiente: [ [1,6], [3, 4], [ ...]] donde serializas el arreglo y lo imprimes al archivo "union". Luego lo lees y cargas el arreglo a la memoria. Quizá debas usar un mapa o un [array asociativo](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Podría implementarlo en java o C/++/# pero esta pregunta es de python :P

Comment: ¿Como es exactamente la estructura de tus txt? deberias agregarlo a la pregunta y si has intentado algún código también. Cargando adecuadamente cada línea en un diccionario es trivial unirlos y pasarlos a `outfile`.

Comment: {'ID': '30', 'Nombre': 'ECONOMIA I', 'Codigo': 'COFI-214'}

Comment: ese seria la estuctura interna de los archivos

Answer (score 2):

Supongamos que tenemos dos txt de la forma:

**archivo1.txt**:

> {'ID': '30', 'Nombre': 'ECONOMIA I', 'Codigo': 'COFI-214'}
>   {'ID': '31', 'Nombre': 'ECONOMIA I', 'Codigo': 'COFI-216'}
>   {'ID': '32', 'Nombre': 'ECONOMIA I', 'Codigo': 'COFI-250'}
>   {'ID': '33', 'Nombre': 'ECONOMIA I', 'Codigo': 'COFI-241'}

**archivo2.txt**:

> {'Fecha': '30/10/2016', 'Hora': '10:40:00'}
>   {'Fecha': '10/02/2017', 'Hora': '23:45:00'}
>   {'Fecha': '07/12/2016', 'Hora': '15:30:00'}
>   {'Fecha': '01/05/2016', 'Hora': '03:12:00'}

Imaginemos que queremos obtener un tercer archivo que contenga el diccionario fruto de unir el diccionario de una fila de ***archivo1.txt*** con el  de otra fila de ***archivo2.txt***.

Podríamos simplemente leer ambos archivos aislar las líneas y concatenar cadenas adecuadamente:

```
with open('archivo1.txt') as f1, open('archivo2.txt') as f2, open('archivounion.txt', 'w') as of:
    line_1 = f1.readlines()[0].strip()
    line_2 = f2.readlines()[5].strip()
    out_line = "{}, {}".format(line_1[:-1], line_2[1:])
    of.write(out_line)
```

No obstante **esto no es realmente unir dos diccionarios ya que esto implica eliminar claves repetidas y actualizar valores de ser necesario**.

Posiblemente la forma más apropiada de hacer esto sea crear dos diccionarios Python a partir de las filas, para lo cual tenemos varias opciones, entre ellas:

- Construir el diccionario "manualmente" usando solo los métodos de las cadenas para parsear la línea:

  ```
  def str_to_dict(cad):
      return {key: value for item in cad[1:-1].replace("'", "").split(", ")
                         for key, value in (item.split(": "),)}
  ```
- Usar [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

  Podemos cargar el diccionario usando eval:

  ```
  diccionario = eval(linea)
  ```

  El problema es que `eval` evalúa cualquier expresión Python válida, lo que lo hace muy peligroso ante entradas de usuario o fuentes de datos no controladas. Hay formas de filtrar la entrada para reducir el riesgo de ataques de inyección de código, pero en este caso es mejor usar  `ast.literal_eval` directamente, que solo permite un conjunto restringido de estructuras literales (listas, diccionarios, conjuntos, tuplas, boleanos, `None`, cadenas y números):

  ```
  >>> from ast import literal_eval
  >>> cadena = "{'ID': '30', 'Nombre': 'ECONOMIA I', 'Codigo': 'COFI-214'}"
  >>> diccionario = literal_eval(cadena)
  >>> print(diccionario['Nombre'])
  ECONOMIA I
  ```
- Usar el módulo json, en concreto [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

  ```
  >>> import json
  >>> cad = '{"ID": "30", "Nombre": "ECONOMIA I", "Codigo": "COFI-214"}'
  >>> diccionario = json.loads(cad)
  >>> diccionario
  {'ID': '30', 'Nombre': 'ECONOMIA I', 'Codigo': 'COFI-214'}
  ```

  El problema es que la sintaxis de JSON no es idéntica a la usada por Python para los diccionarios, por ejemplo JSON requiere que los nombres de las propiedades estén entrecomillados usando comillas dobles.

Hecho esto solo falta unir ambos diccionarios. Para ello podemos hacer uso de `dict.update`.

```
>>> a = {'ID': '30', 'Nombre': 'ECONOMIA I', 'Codigo': 'COFI-214'} 
>>> b = {'Fecha': '30/10/2016', 'Hora': '10:40:00'}

>>> a.update(b)
>>> print(a)
{'ID': '30', 'Nombre': 'ECONOMIA I', 'Codigo': 'COFI-214', 'Fecha': '30/10/2016', 'Hora': '10:40:00'}
```

Si no queremos modificar ninguno de los diccionarios originales recurrimos a `copy.deepcopy()`:

```
>>> import copy
>>> a = {'ID': '30', 'Nombre': 'ECONOMIA I', 'Codigo': 'COFI-214'} 
>>> b = {'Fecha': '30/10/2016', 'Hora': '10:40:00'}
>>> c = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> c.update(b)
>>> print(c)
{'ID': '30', 'Nombre': 'ECONOMIA I', 'Codigo': 'COFI-214', 'Fecha': '30/10/2016', 'Hora': '10:40:00'}
```

En **Python >= 3.6** podemos simplemente hacer:

```
>>> a = {'ID': '30', 'Nombre': 'ECONOMIA I', 'Codigo': 'COFI-214'} 
>>> b = {'Fecha': '30/10/2016', 'Hora': '10:40:00'}
>>> c = {**a, **b}
>>> print(c)
{'ID': '30', 'Nombre': 'ECONOMIA I', 'Codigo': 'COFI-214', 'Fecha': '30/10/2016', 'Hora': '10:40:00'}
```

Con estos conceptos podemos crear una función para hacer lo que quieres:

```
import ast
import copy


def join_dicts(d1, d2):
    copy_dict = copy.deepcopy(d1)
    copy_dict.update(d2)
    return copy_dict

def get_lines(file, lines):
    with open(file) as f:
        return {i: string for i, string in enumerate(f) if i in lines}

def join_dicts_txt(file1, file2, out_file, rows):
    with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2, open(out_file, 'w') as of:
        idxs1, idxs2 = zip(*rows)
        lines1 = get_lines(file1, idxs1)
        lines2 = get_lines(file2, idxs2)

        lines_gen = (str(join_dicts(ast.literal_eval(lines1[r1]),
                                    ast.literal_eval(lines2[r2])
                                   )
                        ) + '\n' for r1, r2 in rows
                    )

        of.writelines(lines_gen)
```

En Python >= 3.6 podemos simplemente hacer:

```
import ast



def get_lines(file, lines):
    with open(file) as f:
        return {i: string for i, string in enumerate(f) if i in lines}

def join_dicts_txt(file1, file2, out_file, rows):
    with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2, open(out_file, 'w') as of:
        idxs1, idxs2 = zip(*rows)
        lines1 = get_lines(file1, idxs1)
        lines2 = get_lines(file2, idxs2)

        lines_gen = (str({**ast.literal_eval(lines1[r1]),
                          **ast.literal_eval(lines2[r2])}
                        ) + '\n' for r1, r2 in rows
                    )

        of.writelines(lines_gen)
```

La función recibe como parámetros los tres archivos (entrada1, entrada2 y salida) y una tupla/lista con las parejas de líneas a unir. Por ejemplo, si queremos que se unan el primer diccionario de ***archivo1.txt*** con el tercero de ***archivo2.txt*** y el segundo de ***archivo1.txt*** con es cuarto de ***archivo2.txt*** el parámetro `rows` debe ser `((0,2),(1,3))`. Para este ejemplo llamaríamos a la función así:

```
join_dicts_txt('archivo1.txt', 'archivo2.txt', 'archivounion.txt', ((0,2),(1,3)))
```

La salida es:

**archivounion.txt**:

> ```
> {'ID': '30', 'Nombre': 'ECONOMIA I', 'Codigo': 'COFI-214', 'Fecha': '07/12/2016', 'Hora': '15:30:00'}    
> {'ID': '31', 'Nombre': 'ECONOMIA I', 'Codigo': 'COFI-216', 'Fecha': '01/05/2016', 'Hora': '03:12:00'}
> ```

Para tu ejemplo (unir diccionario de linea 1 con diccionario de linea 6) deberias llamar a la función así:

```
join_dicts_txt('archivo1.txt', 'archivo2.txt', 'archivounion.txt', [(0, 5)))
```

> **Nota**: Se ha prescindido del método `readlines` (usado en el primer ejemplo) porque con este método cargamos en una lista todas las líneas del fichero,  lo cual no es problema para archivos pequeños pero para archivos relativamente grandes es ineficiente y muy agresivo en el uso de RAM, más aún si al final solo vamos a usar unas cuantas de las líneas del fichero.