# Leer un diccionario desde un archivo de texto en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy tratando de leer un diccionario desde un archivo de texto, dicho archivo tiene una estructura como la siguiente:

```
{'foo': 2, 'hola': 'Hello world!'}
```

He investigado y hay recomendaciones de utilizar el modulo JSON pero quisiera saber si existe alguna otra manera, muchas gracias.

Comment: si no quieres usar `JSON` puedes usar `eval("{'foo': 2, 'hola': 'Hello world!'}")`

Comment: [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) del módulo `ast` es la solución segura (`eval` puede ser peligroso al evaluar cualquier expresión Python válida) si no quieres usar JSON. `import ast`; `d = ast.literal_eval("{'foo': 2, 'hola': 'Hello world!'}")`

Comment: @Blasito lo intentaré, muchas gracias.

Comment: @FJSevilla Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: @FJSevilla muy interesante. Suelo usar mucho el eval, pero ahora, gracias a tu comentario me he puesto a investigar más sobre ello y estoy analizando la posibilidad de migrar algunos códigos. Un saludo!

Comment: @Blasito `eval` y `exec`son herramientas muy poderosas y  útiles en algunos casos  (expresiones matemáticas, apps con consolas con habilidad de ejecutar código como en juegos, etc) pero muy peligrosas en otros, especialmente sin barreras adecuadas y cuando no controlamos la fuente de las expresiones a evaluar (p.e entradas de usuario pasadas directamente a `eval`). Un ejemplo, imagina que hemos importado  `os` en nuestro script, ¡un usuario "malvado" puede eliminar sin problemas archivos del sistema a placer inyectando código solo limitado por los permisos del usuario que ejecutó el script !

Comment: @LuisMiguel creía recordar haber contestado a una pregunta similar a esta, pero no la encontraba... [Unir dos diccionarios procedentes de archivos de texto en los que cada fila es la representación de un diccionario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/65134/15089). La pregunta originalmente difiere algo pero su solución requiere de lo mismo por lo que preguntas, crear un diccionario a partir de su representación en un archivo de texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el siguiente script puedes tener en una variable un diccionario desde un archivo:

```py
with open('/tmp/dict.txt', 'r') as dict_file:
    dict_text = dict_file.read()
    dict_from_file = eval(dict_text)
```

En tu caso deberías modificar `/tmp/dict.txt` por la ruta a tu archivo de texto.

Sin embargo, te recomiendo que utilices JSON debido a que es un formato estándar.

Una mejora que puedes realizar al script es poner una excepción en caso de que el texto del archivo no coincida con el formato esperado.