# Usar diccionario en archivo .ini con configparser.ConfigParser

Tags: python, python-3.x, configuración

¿Cómo puedo iterar entre las claves y valores en un diccionario definido en archivo INI en donde ambos campos son cadenas?

Dentro del archivo ***config.ini*** tengo:

```
proxy : {'Brasil':'186.233.104.25:8080',
         'Chile':'190.82.76.58:32570',
         'Ecuador':'186.3.228.98:8080',
         'venezuela':'190.121.227.174:3128',
         'venezuela':'190.121.227.174:3128',
         'Colombia':'191.102.83.146:80',
         'Paraguay':'190.93.176.70:8080'}
```

e intento acceder al diccionario de esta forma:

```
def __init__(self, Cons):

    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(testdir + '\config.ini')

    self.proxy = config.get(Cons, 'proxy')
    print(repr(self.proxy))
    for pais, ip in proxy.items():
        Pais  = str(pais)
        ip = str(ip)
```

Pero tengo el error:

> Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Salida de `print(repr(self.proxy))`

```
"{'Brasil':'186.233.104.25:8080',\n'Chile':'190.82.76.58:32570',\n'Ecuador':'186.3.228.98:8080',\n'venezuela':'190.121.227.174:3128',\n'venezuela':'190.121.227.174:3128',\n'Colombia':'191.102.83.146:80',\n'Paraguay':'190.93.176.70:8080'}"
```

Comment: El tipo de dato almacenado en el diccionario es indiferente, lo que dice el error es que `self.proxy` no es un diccionario, es una cadena ¿Quizá un json?¿O la representación de un diccionario Python? Si es lo que comento, mírate: [Unir dos diccionarios procedentes de archivos de texto en los que cada fila es la representación de un diccionario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/65134/15089)

Comment: No, yo lo estoy creando el diccionario manualmente con esos valores

Comment: Pues algo falla antes del `for`...  porque `self.proxy` en ese momento nos es un diccionario, es una cadena (`str`). Haz `print(repr(self.proxy))` justo antes del `for` a ver que te imprime antes del error. O creas mal el diccionario o reasignas a self.proxy en algún momento,

Comment: @FJSevilla Agrege la salida de self.proxy

Comment: Como te han dicho tiene toda la pinta de que ``self.proxy`` es un json y que tienes que convertirlo en un diccionario usando el módulo json.

Comment: @FJSevilla listo editada la respuesta

Comment: @Sebastian efectivamente es una cadena como puedes ver, no un diccionario. Si tu lo creaste, y lo hiciste correctamente, en algún momento lo has pasado a cadena sin querer. Puedes volverlo a pasar a dict como muestro en mi respuesta a la pregunta anterior, pero si debe ser un diccionario, algo tienes mal en tu código antes del que muestras, sería bueno que agregaras algo más de código (especialmente cómo lo creas).

Comment: @FJSevilla agrege el codigo completo de la llamada que estoy probando con el modulo configparser, muchas gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por defecto `ConfigParser` tiene solo tres métodos que permiten la conversión de tipos, `getboolean`, `getint` y `getfloat`. Para parsear correctamente el diccionario, necesitas especificar con la ayuda del argumento `converters` del constructor como queremos que se procese el diccionario.

Para ello se le pasa un diccionario en el que la clave será el nombre (al que luego accedemos mediante el método `getnombre()` y la clave un callable que reciba la cadena y retorne el objeto convertido. Podemos crear el diccionario a partir de la cadena usando `ast.literal_eval`.

Partiendo por ejemplo de este **config.ini**:

```
[BaseConfig]
proxy = {'Brasil':'186.233.104.25:8080',
         'Chile':'190.82.76.58:32570',
         'Ecuador':'186.3.228.98:8080',
         'Venezuela':'190.121.227.174:3128',
         'Colombia':'191.102.83.146:80',
         'Paraguay':'190.93.176.70:8080'}
```

para poder acceder a él:

```
import ast
import configparser


config = configparser.ConfigParser(converters={'dict': lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)})
config.read('config.ini')

proxy = config.getdict("BaseConfig", "proxy")
for pais, ip in proxy.items():
    print(f"{pais}, {ip}")
```

---

Ten en cuenta que también puedes usar una sección propia para los datos de tu diccionario, lo que simplifica mucho todo:

```
[Proxy]
Brasil: 186.233.104.25:8080
Chile: 190.82.76.58:32570
Ecuador: 186.3.228.98:8080
Venezuela: 190.121.227.174:3128
Colombia: 191.102.83.146:80
Paraguay: 190.93.176.70:8080
```

y para acceder:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

proxy = config["Proxy"]
for pais, ip in proxy.items():
    print(f"{pais}, {ip}")
```

---

Otra posibilidad es usar un archivo .json:

```
{
    "BaseConfig": {
        "Proxy": {
            "Brasil":"186.233.104.25:8080",
            "Chile":"190.82.76.58:32570",
            "Ecuador":"186.3.228.98:8080",
            "Venezuela":"190.121.227.174:3128",
            "Colombia":"191.102.83.146:80",
            "Paraguay":"190.93.176.70:8080"
        }
    }
}
```

luego accedes a él:

```
import json

with open("config.json") as f:
    config = json.load(f)

proxy = config["BaseConfig"]["Proxy"]
for pais, ip in proxy.items():
    print(f"{pais}, {ip}")
```

---

Por último, ya fuera de la stdlib es usar un archivo [YAML](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) con [PyYAML](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/), que por ejemplo te permite anidar secciones, tal como pareces pretender tú en un inicio, y es un formato muy legible para humanos:

```
BaseConfig:
    Proxy:
        Brasil: 186.233.104.25:8080
        Chile: 190.82.76.58:32570
        Ecuador: 186.3.228.98:8080
        Venezuela: 190.121.227.174:3128
        Colombia: 191.102.83.146:80
        Paraguay: 190.93.176.70:8080
```

luego accedemos a él algo así:

```
import yaml

with open('config.ini') as f:
    config = yaml.safe_load(f)

proxy = config["BaseConfig"]["Proxy"]
for pais, ip in proxy.items():
    print(f"{pais}, {ip}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tienes un archivo llamado **config.ini** con los siguientes datos:

```
{
"Brasil":"186.233.104.25:8080",
"Chile":"190.82.76.58:32570",
"Ecuador":"186.3.228.98:8080",
"venezuela":"190.121.227.174:3128",
"venezuela":"190.121.227.174:3128",
"Colombia":"191.102.83.146:80",
"Paraguay":"190.93.176.70:8080"
}
```

Puedes llamar a cada una de sus valores por su clave así:

```
import json
conf = json.loads(open('config.ini').read())
brasil = conf['Brasil']
print(brasil)
```

O iterarlo así tal como lo estas haciendo

```
import json
conf = json.loads(open('config.ini').read())

for pais, ip in conf.items():
    Pais = str(pais)
    ip = str(ip)
    print(Pais + ", " + ip)
```

Pero con una salvedad: Los elementos deben venir con comillas dobles no con comillas simples. `"Chile":"190.82.76.58:32570",`

Answer (score 0):

Si no me equivoco, la función get de un diccionario, funciona así... (Valor a recuperar, y valor default en caso de no existir)
Osea, tendrías que poner config.get('proxy')
Al poner get(const,'proxy') estás buscando un objeto igual a const, y al no ser encontrado obtienes el valor del segundo parámetro, por eso te dice que el str no tiene items